# Have a text box that call a procedure from my class in VBA

Tags: class, vba, textbox

I am new in VBA and classes.
I have this procedure in my class:

```
Public Sub InputData()

Dim blnLoaded As Boolean
Dim path As String
Dim file As String

path = MyForm.TextPath

file = MyForm.TextFile

If LoadData(path, file) = False Then

    MsgBox FileErrorString
Else
    blnLoaded = LoadData(path, file)
End If

End Sub
```

and I want to call it using 2 text boxes in my form:

```
Private Sub CmdLoad_Click()

Call clsData.InputData

End Sub
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of your class first.

Something like this depending on your implementation of your class:

```
Private Sub CmdLoad_Click()

  Dim myData as New clsData

  Call myData.InputData()

End Sub
```